# Как вычислить возраст по датам рождения в одном столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Необходимо вычислить возраст на основании дат рождения из столбца "birthday" и сохранить его в столбец "age".

На мой вариант:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df_students = pd.read_csv("students.csv", parse_dates=['birthday'])
df_students.dropna(how='any', inplace = True)

#Вычисляем возраст студентов:
df_students["today"] = datetime.now().date()
df_students['birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df_students['birthday'])
df_students["age"] = (df_students["today"] - df_students["birthday"])
```

Получаю ошибку:

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 235-05-31 00:00:00

[Датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13CPJg6zmcrPU0WDPzE7nKCvttDVQ5Wtc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a

Comment: у вас правда есть студент, которому 1786 лет ?? :-D

Comment: Такой датасет. Значит, возраст нужно будет еще проверять на неадекватные значения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

замените:

```
df_students['birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df_students['birthday'])
```

на

```
df_students['birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df_students['birthday'], errors="coerce")
```

возраст (в годах) лучше считать так:

```
df_students["age"] = \
    (pd.to_datetime("today") - df_students["birthday"]).astype('<m8[Y]')
```

---

**UPD:** тест на вашем датасете:

```
In [62]: df_students = pd.read_csv("students.csv")

In [63]: df_students['birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df_students['birthday'], errors="coerce")

In [64]: df_students["age"] = \
    ...:     (pd.to_datetime("today") - df_students["birthday"]).astype('<m8[Y]')
```

результат:

```
In [65]: df_students
Out[65]:
          id_                                id              city   birthday   age
0        1325  35e8a1938b9a33d5e45c8f4451c4309a               NaN        NaT   NaN
1        7503  6c3e52be632fc50de9640147e4017dcd            Москва 1979-10-23  41.0
2        8972  2033122d7c9b24b36eebc468d5259642               NaN        NaT   NaN
3        9235  a6ae278c0eab719b3784e5ea147c128f            Москва        NaT   NaN
4        9588  51b25c9afd20d178ef3c07276df38e2d  Великий Новгород        NaT   NaN
...       ...                               ...               ...        ...   ...
43825  124251  a65ccacbe0226b345f195d02e676aa04               NaN 2000-11-21  20.0
43826  124338  148f1375e4135e779053a0d4b2a63857               NaN 1999-10-20  21.0
43827  124363  05fa419f832fa78ad6e7a5f90b0f71e6               NaN        NaT   NaN
43828  124377  9ff58c490f6ee5b013e7f62140ee3d79               NaN 1998-04-18  22.0
43829  124445  5c02b021cef9b775bb874bf1658ffb58               NaN        NaT   NaN

[43830 rows x 5 columns]

In [66]: df.dtypes
Out[66]:
id_                  int64
id                  object
city                object
birthday    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Первый вариант выдал ошибку: "TypeError: cannot subtract DatetimeArray from ndarray". Второй сработал

Comment: @AndrewTim, не совсем понял о каком первом варианте вы говорите

Comment: df_students['birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df_students['birthday'], errors="coerce")

Comment: @AndrewTim, не знаю что и как вы делаете - я добавил в ответ код, который читает CSV файл, преобразует дату рождения в datetime и считает возраст - все работает отлично

Comment: Всё работает, это я туплю.